# Address dynamic created content in wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic

I am creating a dynamic GUI for learning purposes. After clicking on a "+" button the user can add the itemControl template.

What is the best practise to get the element by a name (in this case x:Name="lblName" which should be available but has to been build first) of dynamically created elements?

MainWindow.xaml:

```
    <ItemsControl Name="icDynamicTableColumn">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="0,0,0,5">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Height="23" Width="auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="lblName" Text="{Binding Textfield}" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
        [...]
        public ObservableCollection<DynamicTableColumn> items = new ObservableCollection<DynamicTableColumn>();
        [...]

        public MainWindow() 
        {
                [...]
                InitializeComponent();
                icDynamicTableColumn.ItemsSource = items;
        }

        public class DynamicTableColumn
        {
                public string Description
                {
                        get {
                                return _description;
                        }

                        set {
                                [...]
                        }
                }
                private string _description;
                public string Textfield { get; set; }
        }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve? Do you want to get the Name or the Element which has this name?

Comment: Clearify: handle to the dynamic created object to access Methods.

Comment: There are indeed multiple ways, however all not so easy (as the ItemsControl does not expose a method to get the (visual) container for an item). What do you want to achieve if you have the TextBox? Would it be enough to be notified if the user changes the text?

Comment: In general I was searching for a architectural approach for problems regarding dynamic created content. As I looked for a solution like looking through the visual-tree it seemed to take longer as more objects there are. Nonetheless in particular to this project it would be enough to set focus to these dynamically created elements and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is enough to do some operation when the user adds a new item or changes the text, I would propose to use events, e.g. Loaded or TextChanged.

If you really need to find the textbox dynamically, you could use the following code:

```
    ObservableCollection<DynamicTableColumn> Collection = new ObservableCollection<DynamicTableColumn>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        icDynamicTableColumn.ItemsSource = Collection;

        Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    }

    private StackPanel Panel;

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //find the panel that contains the children
        Panel = (StackPanel)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(
                 VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(icDynamicTableColumn, 0), 0), 0);
    }

    TextBox GetTextBoxForIndex(int index)
    {
        //get the child for a given index
        var presenter = (ContentPresenter)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(Panel, index);
        return (TextBox)presenter.ContentTemplate.FindName("lblName", presenter);
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Collection.Add(new DynamicTableColumn());
        //make sure that the Textbox was loaded
        icDynamicTableColumn.UpdateLayout();

        var textBox = GetTextBoxForIndex(Collection.Count - 1);
    }
```

Just be aware that this assumes that you use an ItemsControl and did not change it's (Control)Template. If you often have to do this, you could create your own ItemsControl (derive from it) and expose the GetTextBoxForIndex method. However, you should do some security checks (e.g. the index in the range and the presenter has to be loaded).